# Parse exception on SaveAsync()

Tags: c#, parse-platform, xamarin

Occasionally (about 1 in 6 times) when attempting to create then save a parseObject, I get the following exception thrown

> at System.DateTime.ParseExact (System.String s, System.String[] formats, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles style) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at System.DateTime.ParseExact (System.String s, System.String format, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles style) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at System.DateTime.ParseExact (System.String s, System.String format, IFormatProvider provider) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at Parse.ParseClient.ParseDate (System.String input) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at Parse.ParseObject.MergeMagicFields (IDictionary`2 data) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at Parse.ParseObject.MergeFromServer (IDictionary`2 data) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at Parse.ParseObject.MergeAfterSave (IDictionary`2 result) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at Parse.ParseObject+c__DisplayClass1f.b__1b (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1 t) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskActionInvoker+FuncTaskInvoke`2[System.Tuple`2[System.Net.HttpStatusCode,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]],System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Tuple`2[System.Net.HttpStatusCode,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]]]].Invoke (System.Threading.Tasks.Task owner, System.Object state, System.Threading.Tasks.Task context) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x00000] in :0 
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThreadStart () [0x00000] in :0

I am using .net parse version 1.3.1.

The code causing the error looks like this:

```
ParseObject po = new ParseObject( "Journey" );
po.ObjectId = journey.ID;
po["audioCount"] = journey.AudioFiles.Count;
po["locationPointCount"] = journey.LocationPoints.Count;
po["photoCount"] = journey.PhotoFiles.Count;
po["videoCount"] = journey.VideoFiles.Count;
po["startTime"] = journey.StartTime;
po["endTime"] = journey.EndTime;
po["notes"] = journey.Notes;
po["isInProgress"] = journey.IsInProgress;

po.AddRangeUniqueToList( "audioFiles", audioFiles );
po.AddRangeUniqueToList( "photoFiles", photoFiles );
po.AddRangeUniqueToList( "videoFiles", videoFiles );

po.ACL = new ParseACL(ParseUser.CurrentUser);
po["user"] = ParseUser.CurrentUser;

await po.SaveAsync();
```

Thanks for any help

Edit:
Removing "startTime" and "endTime" from the ParseObject does not resolve the issue.

Edit: 
For the sake of more information, here is the disassembly of the "MergeMagicFields" method which appears to be causing the problem. The only paths that end up calling "ParseData" appear to be related to parses internal data.

```
internal virtual void MergeMagicFields( IDictionary<string, object> data )
{
    lock( this.mutex )
    {
        if( data.ContainsKey( "objectId" ) )
        {
            this.SetObjectIdInternal( data["objectId"] as string );
            this.hasBeenFetched = true;
            this.OnPropertyChanged( "IsDataAvailable" );
            data.Remove( "objectId" );
        }
        if( data.ContainsKey( "createdAt" ) )
        {
            this.CreatedAt = new DateTime?( ParseClient.ParseDate( data["createdAt"] as string ) );
            data.Remove( "createdAt" );
        }
        if( data.ContainsKey( "updatedAt" ) )
        {
            this.UpdatedAt = new DateTime?( ParseClient.ParseDate( data["updatedAt"] as string ) );
            data.Remove( "updatedAt" );
        }
        if( data.ContainsKey( "ACL" ) )
        {
            ParseACL parseACL = new ParseACL( data["ACL"] as IDictionary<string, object> );
            this.serverData["ACL"] = parseACL;
            this.AddToHashedObjects( parseACL );
            data.Remove( "ACL" );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well, it's clearly an error parsing a date, and you have two of those.  So log the values and see which ones are causing the exception.  Is there a pattern?

Comment: I have tried removing everything that is related to a date, and still get the same problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What? Errors aren't magical.  It says you have a problem with some `DateTime.ParseExact` you're doing.  I promise it's not lying to you.

Comment: I can see that. It could be one of the internal DateTimes that parse uses also (createdAt or updatedAt possibly?). I have run the code removing everything to do with DateTime, and still get the same error, I promise.

Comment: Why not check the values of `journey.StartTime` and `journey.EndTime` when that exception is thrown? It should be obvious why it's not able to parse the value.

Comment: @grovesNL I have since removed those from the code, but I checked them just the be triply sure. There is no difference between the variables when the program fails and when it doesnt. The both log the same and without issue.

Comment: @ChrisWebb: In that case, there is another `DateTime` somewhere in code that you haven't provided. You need to figure out what property or method is related to `DateTime` when the exception is thrown.

Comment: @grovesNL I wish that was the case. No other data is being set on the parse object. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @ChrisWebb: Maybe you should look into what property `Parse.ParseObject.MergeMagicFields` believes is a `DateTime`.

Comment: @grovesNL MergeMagicFields definitely contains handling for parses own internal "createdAt" and "updatedAt" properties, and they are the only blocks which end up calling ParseClient.ParseDate. This leads me to suspect that the issue is with parse internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[In case anyone else is having this issue]

After reporting the issue to Facebook, it appears that it is an issue on their end.

You can follow progress of the issue here:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/789062014466095/